# SQL ordering with the max

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have the following table:

```
TKG   hour  CAP SWITCH  CALLS
AAA   7     45  HH      56
AAA   8     35  HH      76
AAA   9     25  HH      43
BBB   7     32  LL      5
BBB   8     43  LL      65
BBB   9     434 LL      65
CCC   7     54  JJ      43
CCC   8     564 JJ      43
CCC   9     54  JJ      65
ddd   7     10  MM      4
ddd   8     10  MM      3
ddd   9     10  MM      5
```

I need to order by the TKG with the max CAP so the output will look like this:

```
TKG hour    CAP SWITCH  CALLS
AAA 7       45  HH      56
BBB 9       434 LL      65
CCC 8       564 JJ      43
ddd 7       10  MM      4
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Sql server 2005+, then you can use `row_number()` and `partition by TKG` and `order by cap desc`:

```
select TKG, hour, CAP, switch, Calls
from 
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by TKG order by cap desc) rn
  from yourtable 
) t1
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bf9a/3)

Result:

```
| TKG | HOUR | CAP | SWITCH | CALLS |
-------------------------------------
| AAA |    7 |  45 |     HH |    56 |
| BBB |    9 | 434 |     LL |    65 |
| CCC |    8 | 564 |     JJ |    43 |
| ddd |    7 |  10 |     MM |     4 |
```

Comment: +1 You did it while I was formatting the question. How do you do those fiddles so quickly? a secret?

Comment: @Kaf I typically work backwards, I do the fiddle first to make sure the query works before I post.  It means I lose the as fastest gun in the west but I want to be sure the query is right.

Comment: Hmm, you are still lightning fast man. (I couldn't understand the question at first as `HH` was `under CAP column` and he was asking for a `MAX of HH`. I did the community work ;) )

Answer (score 1):

this one works in oracle

```
  select TKG,hour,CAP,SWITCH,CALLS from (select a1.*,rank over (partition  by TKG, order by CAP) rnk 
    from table a1) where rnk=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select * from table 
 where  cap=(select max(cap) from table group by tkg)
 group by tkg
```

or

```
select top 1 * from table
 order by cap desc
```

or

```
 select * from table
 order by cap desc
  limit (1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.* from Tab a
join
(
Select TKG,max(CAP) as CAP from Tab Group by TKG
) b on a.TKG=b.TKG and a.CAP=b.CAP
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the max values and into a sub query and link to this in an inner join on the CAP val  Other

```
SELECT TKG, hour,  CAP, SWITCH,  CALLS
INNER JOIN --GET THE MAX CAP FOR EACH TKG
(SELECT TKG, MAX(CAP) AS MaxCAP
FROM myTable
GROUP BY TKG
) AS MaxCap
ON MyTable.Cap= MaxCap.MaxCAP
```